# How to automatically fill all info in the 2nd payment but not 3rd or 4th payments in Stripe?

Tags: python, django, django-views, stripe-payments, checkout

With the Django's code below, I'm testing [payment_method_options.card.setup_future_usage](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_method_options-card-setup_future_usage) in **Stripe Checkout** in `test` mode:

```py
# "views.py"

def test(request):                                 # Here
    customer = stripe.Customer.search(query="email:'mytest@gmail.com'", limit=1)
    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        customer=customer["data"][0]["id"] if customer.has_more else None,
        line_items=[
            {
                "price_data": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "unit_amount_decimal": 1000,
                    "product_data": {
                        "name": "T-shirt",
                        "description": "Good T-shirt",
                    },
                },
                "quantity": 2,
            }
        ],
        payment_method_options={ # Here
            "card": {
                "setup_future_usage": "on_session",
            },
        },
        mode='payment',
        success_url='http://localhost:8000',
        cancel_url='http://localhost:8000'
    )

    return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)
```

For the 1st payment with `mytest@gmail.com`, I need to manually fill all info as shown below:

[image]

But, even for the 2st and 3rd payments with `mytest@gmail.com`, I still need to manually fill all info without automatically filled shown below:

[image]

Finally, for the 4th payment with `mytest@gmail.com`, all info is automatically filled as shown below:

[image]

So, how to automatically fill all info in the 2nd payment but not 3rd or 4th payments in `test` and `live` modes?

Answer (score 0):

In the first payment, `Securely save my information for 1-click checkout` is checked. This means that the payment method will be saved in [Link](https://stripe.com/payments/link) (payment method storage provided by Stripe) for future payment.

In the second payment, there's this `Log in` option beside the email. If you log in with it, you should see the same saved payment method shown as the fourth payment. It's likely that you were not logged in in second and third payment, so the saved payment method isn't shown.